# How do I export address book from N97

Tags: sync, address-book, symbian

I need to copy my numbers from my private Nokia to my office BB. I have not found a way to export my phone numbers from ovi or elsewhere. On Mac iSync stopped working with snow leopard and OVI on windows does not export. I do not mind using a windows suggestion. I lost a description on how to use the ovi backup files in another program.

What I have done so far

- terminal: sudo open -a iSync.app - it launched but iSync said "this device is not supported by iSync"
- went here http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/isync/compatibility-and-download
- found a plugin (I am sure that was not there a while ago :| )
- Checked software version 22.0.110
- installed plugin
- Ran iSync which found and installed my N97 device successfully.
- synced. It stopped with *The connection was lost while talking to the phone.* http://discussions.europe.nokia.com/t5/Nseries-and-S60-Smartphones/N97-iSync-Multimedia-Transfer-Modem/m-p/568560 no news since Jan 2010.
- Tried to download and install http://best-vcard.en.softonic.com/symbian but the installer fails :(

I simply do not understand why Nokia is giving us such a hard time. I would not have considered switching from Nokia if Mac had been better supported. It is so frustrating that they just seem not to care losing Nokia fanbois like me - especially since I am this outspoken on the net and what i say on popular forums gets indexed by google fast. I am very close to just go iPhone here.

Hope someone has Nokia's ears

---

UPDATE:
I Downloaded [NbuExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbuexplorer/) from sourceforge. It will extract everything from an OVI backup into VCF, VCS and VMG files.

Very useful software and free.

Comment: http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/n97/software

Comment: Yeeees? What do I do there, that I haven't already?

Comment: You're right SonyEricsson or Samsung, never ever Nokia.

Comment: Hmm 5 bucks... http://store.ovi.com/content/15392?clickSource=publisher+channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is:

Download [NbuExplorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbuexplorer/) from sourceforge. It will extract everything from an OVI backup into VCF, VCS and VMG files.

Very useful software and free.

For PCSuite (not tried) I found [NokNokWhosThere](http://sourceforge.net/projects/noknokwhosthere/) also at sourceforge

Answer (score 0):

http://discussions.info.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2136675&tstart=-2

You may want to try

- launching isync via an admin account
- `mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.syncserver.plist ~/.Trash/`

Comment: Nope. No luck there either